# How do I use socket.connect?

Tags: python, networking

I'm a novice at both python and networking. What address and port should I enter into `s.connect`? Also, am I using variables correctly in `s.connect`?

```
import socket
recAddress = input("What is the address of the receiver of your messages?")
recPort = input("What port is the receiver using?")
def mysend(sock, msg):
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < MSGLEN:
        sent = sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((recAddress, recPort))

i = 2
mysend(s, str(i))
```

Comment: Any address you want to `connect` to?

Comment: I'm using this to send messages over LAN. I have one windows machine and I'm wondering how I can connect to the other machine. Where can I find the other machines port number and address?

Comment: You might want to read about TCP/IP networking and the specifics of the network settings of a Windows machine before trying to send messages. Currently, this does not seem like a programming question to me.

Comment: I don't even know if I'm using LAN correctly. I'm trying to say that I want to send these messages over my local network.

Comment: What do you want to connect to? You can't just connect "to the other machine", you have to connect to _some service on_ the other machine, like a web server or an SMB file-sharing service or a custom program you've written. The port number will then be the port that service is listening to.

Comment: As for getting the machine's address, that's a question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), although I suspect they'd close it for being too trivial and simple, since a simple google search will tell you the answer faster than typing in the question…

Comment: Alright. I guess I've got some reading up to do ahead of me on networking. My only question now is if I'm using the variables recAddress and recPort in s.connect.

Comment: @user3314828: Almost, but not quite. `input` returns a string, but `connect` requires a number for the port. So, you'd need `s.connect((recAddress, int(recPort)))` to make this work. (I'm assuming Python 3.x; in 2.x, you want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`… and then, if you do so, the same is true.)

Comment: Also, as a side note, your `mysend(sock, msg)` function is unnecessary, since it does the same thing as `sock.sendall(msg)`. (Unless you want to add some extra debugging to see why it's failing—e.g., to distinguish between "successfully sent 46/80 bytes, then got an error on the second `send`" and "got an error on the first `send`", in which case writing your own loop around `send` is a great idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't answer the vague question about "how do I know what IP and port to pass to this program", for the reasons explained in the comments.

But for the specific question about your code:

> Also, am I using variables correctly in s.connect?

Almost, but not quite.

You get the values like this:

```
recAddress = input("What is the address of the receiver of your messages?")
recPort = input("What port is the receiver using?")
```

Assuming this is Python 3.x, [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string. But [`connect`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) (for an IPv4 connection) requires a *number* for a port, not a string. So, you have to convert it somewhere.

You could do that immediately on input:

```
recPort = int(input("What port is the receiver using?"))
```

… or you could do it in the `connect` call:

```
s.connect((recAddress, int(recPort)))
```

---

If that assumption is wrong and you're using Python 2.x, then [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) will try to evaluate the input string, which means you'll get a number for the `recPort`… but then you're not reading `recAddress` right, unless you want to force the user to put quotes around the IP address.

In general, you almost never want to use `input`; call [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead—and if you do that, you get a string, and everything is exactly the same as I described for Python 3.x above.

---

Finally, a few side notes:

Instead of explicitly creating an IPv4 socket and calling `connect` on it, it's usually better to call [`create_connection`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection). That way, if you later switch to an IPv6-compatible network, your program will still work fine (as long as users give you an IPv6 address, or a DNS address that resolves to one).

The [`sendall`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) method on sockets already does what you appear to be trying to do manually with your `mysend` function. While it can sometimes be useful to loop around `send` like that explicitly (for example, if you're trying to debug an error, it means you can tell exactly where things went wrong), in general it's simpler to just use `send all`.

Also, within that loop, you're using a constant `MSGLEN`, which you haven't defined anywhere, which obviously isn't going to work. And, even if you *did* define it somewhere, what would you want to happen if `len(msg)` weren't the same as `MSGLEN`? For example, if `MSGLEN` is `4`, and `msg` is `'2'` (as in your example), it will send 2 bytes and then keep trying to send 0 bytes over and over again. Or, if `MSGLEN` is `1` but `msg` is `'42'`, it'll misleadingly send 2 bytes instead of 1. Most likely, you wanted to use `len(msg)` there, not `MSGLEN`.

Comment: I'm entering an IP address into recAddress. Changing it to an integer won't work because of the periods in the address. What data type would work for it?

Comment: @user3314828: The _IP address_ should be a string, but the _port_ should be an integer. (Well, you _can_ use an integer for the IP address as well, by converting each component into a byte and turning them all into a 4-byte integer, but you don't have to do that, and shouldn't…) That's why `s.connect((recAddress, int(recPort)))` works—it leaves `recAddress` as-is, but converts `recPort` to an integer.